# Wildfly 10 bean in jsp sesson scope needs Serializable?

Tags: wildfly

I'm migrating a bunch of web applications from JBoss 4.2.2 to Wildfly 10. For Wildfly 10 I use standalone mode, and use session sharing feature, so all the war files are under the same ear.

I have a jsp file that has a line

```
 <jsp:useBean id="session_counter" class="com.count.CounterBean" scope="session" />
```

When I tried to accessing this page, I got the NotSerializableException error.  I'm not using cluster, no EJB.
I tried to diable the following configuration from standalone.xml, it doesnot work.

```
<cache name="distributable" passivation-store-ref="infinispan" aliases="passivating clustered"/>
```

I only need a java object to be in session scope, is it required to implement Serializable interface? I'm trying to avoid changing code. Does anyone know any configuration or work around for this issue?

The following is the stacktrace:

```
Stacktrace:
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:471)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:402)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:346)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at filters.ProgramNameFilter.doFilter(ProgramNameFilter.java:109)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.infinispan.commons.marshall.NotSerializableException: com.count.CounterBean
        at org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan.session.coarse.CoarseSessionAttributes.setAttribute(CoarseSessionAttributes.java:63)
        at org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow.session.DistributableSession.setAttribute(DistributableSession.java:148)
        at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpSessionImpl.setAttribute(HttpSessionImpl.java:170)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doSetAttribute(PageContextImpl.java:337)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.setAttribute(PageContextImpl.java:317)
        at org.apache.jsp.generic2.generic_005fenter_005fnew.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:176)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.commons.marshall.NotSerializableException: com.count.CounterBean
```

Thanks a lot,
Helen

Comment: Did you use session sharing before? I think if you want to use that, you will probably need it to be serializable.

Comment: No, the project didn't use session sharing before. But because in JBoss 4, the sessionId is the same even across the different context root, and in Wildfly sessionId is different across the different context root, to keep the sessionId the same so the functionality can work, I have to use shared session. I think you are right, to use shared session, the bean has to be serializable.  I guess I have to change code. Thanks a lot for your help.   Helen